# TFDGUIxLoginDialog.VisibleItems Not Displaying When Dialog is Displayed

Tags: firedac, interbase, delphi-12-athens

Using Delphi 12 Athens, patched. FireDAC. developer_interbase2020.

1. FireDAC Connection Editor specifies Driver ID: IB
2. TFDGUIxLoginDialog.VisibleItems contains the following list:

   Server
   InstanceName
   User_Name
   Password
   Database
3. When the dialog is displayed, only User_Name, Password and Database are displayed. Server and InstanceName do not appear.
4. Embarcadero documentation shows that other parameters are possible.

   with FDGUIxLoginDialog1.VisibleItems do begin
   Clear;
   Add('Server');
   Add('User_name=Benutzer');
   Add('Password=Kennwort');
   Add('OSAuthent');
   end;
   FDConnection1.LoginDialog := FDGUIxLoginDialog1;
   FDConnection1.Connected := True;

I have checked the Embarcadero QA Jira but have not been able to find any mention of this behavior. Is there a way to get this to work that avoids writing a lot of code?

TIA

Comment: FWIW: I have the same issue with Delphi 11.3 and IB2020. Unable to find a solution to date...